# Does the phrase "if that's fine with you" require a question mark?

Tags: grammar, questions, question-mark

Say I have the sentence:

> I suggest we do an interview at 12 pm, if that's fine with you.

Is this sentence a direct question which requires a question mark, or should I keep it the way it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either.

Without the question mark, it really means "assuming that's ok with you", which **doesn't require an answer**.  You're saying "I'm assuming it's ok with you.", and the other person can obviously say "Actually, it's not convenient." if they want, but if they're ok with it then they can not respond, or at least not address the question in their response, which is taken as a tacit approval.

With the question mark, you're asking them to reply.

You would tend to use the no-question-mark version in situations where it would normally be expected to be ok, and you're really just being polite by reminding them that they have the option to say it isn't.

If you want an answer, use the question mark.